# Kivy PyInstaller on Appveyor

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, appveyor

I would like to build the executables for my Kivy application using PyInstaller on Appveyor. I have the build working on my own computer, but on Appveyor build I get the following message:

```
OpenGL version detected: 1.1
Version: b'1.1.0'
Vendor: b'Microsoft Corporation'
Renderer: b'GDI Generic'
Try upgrading your graphics drivers and/or your graphics hardware in case of problems.
The application will leave now.
```

I am using the default PyInstaller configuration as described in https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html.

The appveyor.yml is as follows:

```
image: Visual Studio 2015

environment:
  matrix:
    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python34"
      PYTHON_VERSION: "3.4.x" # currently 3.4.3
      PYTHON_ARCH: "32"

    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python34-x64"
      PYTHON_VERSION: "3.4.x" # currently 3.4.3
      PYTHON_ARCH: "64"

install:
  # Install Python (from the official .msi of http://python.org) and pip when
  # not already installed.
  - ps: if (-not(Test-Path($env:PYTHON))) { & appveyor\install.ps1 }

  - "SET PATH=%PYTHON%;%PYTHON%\\Scripts;%PATH%"

  # Check that we have the expected version and architecture for Python
  - "python --version"
  - "python -c \"import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)\""

  - "pip install --disable-pip-version-check --user --upgrade pip"

  # Kivy and pyinstaller included
  - "%CMD_IN_ENV% pip install -r requirements.txt"

  # Saw somewhere on the internet, doesn't work with it nor without it.
  - ps: iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/appveyor/ci/master/scripts/enable-desktop.ps1'))



build_script:
  - "%CMD_IN_ENV% python -m PyInstaller myapp.spec"


artifacts:
  - path: dist\*
```

As far as I see it, it can go two ways:
* somehow prevent kivy pyinstaller hook from using OpenGL
* configure Appveyor to use OpenGL

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: It actually worked out beautifully. I switched to `python35`, `Kivy 1.9.2-dev0` and `kivy.deps.angle`. OpenGL 2.0 was recognized and the build went through. Thanks.

Comment: Posted as an answer ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ilyaf said, but one thing might help you - try to install `kivy.deps.angle` and package it with that + make your app [use the `angle`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.cgl.html). I'm not quite sure if it'll help as there's no GPU, but `angle` translates OpenGL calls to DirectX, which Appveyor seems to have. It's worth trying, though I'm afraid it'll be no-go even with `angle`.

Answer (score 1):

I afraid it is not possible as build happens in Hyper-V VMs which do not have physical GPU...